# Minimal number of checks in case statement to be valid over multiple column range

Tags: sql, oracle, case

given the following table [definition](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f0dcf)

I have a query written as so:

```
select id,  
(  
   case   
      when partial >= 2 and full >=2  
      then sum(partial+full)  
      when partial >=2   
      then partial  
      when full >= 2  
      then full  
      else 0 
   end  
) counts
from Foo
```

What is the minimum number of checks that I have to do to ensure that the inner when clauses:

`partial>=2` and `full >=2`  are not invoked twice.  That is does the case when/then syntax treat everything as else ifs and not just  straight ifs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
select id,  
(  
   case when partial >= 2 then partial else 0 end + 
   case when full >= 2 then full else 0 end  
) counts
from Foo
```

Sample [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/29a9d/1)